# Confusion with example explanation to: show that $(a_k)$ is an eventually constant sequence if it is $D_0$-convergent in set X

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

The full question given in the example is:

Let $X$ be a set and $d_0$ is the discrete metric for $X$.  Suppose that $(a_k)$ is a sequence in $X$ that is $d_0$-convergent.  Show that $(a_k)$ is an eventually constant sequence.

The solution is given as:

Let $(a_k)$ be a sequence in $X$ and suppose it converges (in $d$) to $a ∈ X$.  Then by the definition of convergence, it must be the case that $(d_0(a_k,a))$ is a real null sequence and so, in particular, there is $N∈\mathbb{N}$ such that for $k > N$, $\lvert{d_0(a_k, a)}\lvert<1$.

But $d_0(a_k,a)$ can only equal $0$ or $1$, so this means that there must be $N∈\mathbb{N}$ such that for $k>N$, $d_0(a_k,a)=0$.  Since $d_o$ is a metric on $X$, property M1 tells us that for $k>N, a_k=a$.  In other words, the sequence $(a_k)$ is eventually constant, as required.

I don't understand why they state $\lvert{d_0(a_k, a)}\lvert<1$.  Where does that come from?  It anyone could clarify that for me it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You may pick any $\epsilon>0$. Picking $\epsilon=1$ leads to the desired conclusion.

Comment: How important is it that $ϵ=1$?  If I took it to be 10, would the answer still hold?  I feel like it wouldn't because taking it as less than 1 left the only possible outcome as 0, which was the crux of the explanation if my understanding is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

By definition:

> a sequence $\{a_k\}$ has limit $a$ iff for each real number $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a  number $N$ such that, for every natural number $n > N$ we have $d( a_n,a ) < ϵ$

Use $\epsilon=1$

Comment: Ahh I see.  Thank you!

Comment: How important is it that ϵ=1? If I took it to be 10, would the answer still hold? I feel like it wouldn't because taking it as less than 1 left the only possible outcome as 0, which was the crux of the explanation if my understanding is correct.

Comment: The discrete metric has values in $\{0,1\}$, so any value  $0<\epsilon\le  1$ works.

Comment: Yeah I thought so.  I'm trying to understand this example, so that I can attempt the same question, but in the case of $d(x, y) = 5\lvert{x-y}\lvert + d_0(x, y)$.  I don't think I can use the same argument on it, due to the $5\lvert{a_k-a}\lvert$ part of $d(a_k, a)$ giving other possible answers when I set $ϵ=1$.  Do you have any pointers or hints in showing it in this case?